# Update super attribute price programmatically

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Is there any way to update the price of a super attribute (color in this case) from the product model or some other model?
I already try with the following code:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'mySku');
$configurableProductsData = [];
$configurableProductsData['17163'] = [
    '0' => [
        'label' => 'AZUL',
        'attribute_id' => '193',
        'value_index' => '165',
        'is_percent' => '1',
        'pricing_value' => '15'
    ]
];
$_product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
$_product->save();
```

Successfully create the relationship with the simple product but do not add the discount to the super attribute.